# Can't increase the column header height in a Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I get the following error when compiling:

> ```
> [jrc] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :
>   [jrc]      1. The title section, the page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the page height.
>   [jrc]      2. The page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the page height.
>   [jrc]      3. The page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the last page height.
> ```

The problem is with the following report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ReturnDeliveryNoteColumnHeader" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="30" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="4328d8a4-e5d5-4d7d-9fba-b42407325799">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

The problem occurs when the band height is increased above 30. Another report uses this report as a Subreport, in the Page Header band. I changed the height of the Page Header band, and the Subreport height within the Page Header to 50, but still get the error.

Comment: The template you posted is valid (it is was successfully compiled at my JSS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template starts with

```
<jasperReport ... pageHeight="30" ...>
```

Increasing the height of the column header band above 30, therefore, makes it not fit onto a page anymore.

If you want a higher band, use a page height large enough to house that band.

Answer (score -1):

it is maybe error change the splitType="Stretch" to another method and u used maximum size of page

Comment: SplitType property used for a different things. We should adjust the column header height for this issue.